# Get posts in certain Taxonomy terms for the current page url

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Taxonomies are a bit confusing. I want a "Moods" section for my music posts. So "Moods/Angry", "Moods/Sad", etc. and if you go to *myurl.com/moods/angry/* there will be a list of posts that are tagged in the mood "Angry".

So I can either create a separate template page for each mood "taxonomy-moods-angry.php", "taxonomy-moods-love.php", etc. (this does work) and let wordpress grab the correct template or is there a way to only have 1 template and get the `'terms' =>` from the current page url? So if you're on *myurl.com/moods/love/* it'll show all posts I've added to in the moods/love tag.

I have this in my `functions.php` file:

```
//MOODS TAXONOMY
add_action( 'init', 'create_moods_taxonomy' );
function create_moods_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                           => 'Moods',
        'singular_name'                  => 'Mood',
        'search_items'                   => 'Search Moods',
        'all_items'                      => 'All Moods',
        'edit_item'                      => 'Edit Moods',
        'update_item'                    => 'Update Moods',
        'add_new_item'                   => 'Add New Moods',
        'new_item_name'                  => 'New Moods Name',
        'menu_name'                      => 'Moods',
        'view_item'                      => 'View Moods',
        'popular_items'                  => 'Popular Moods',
        'separate_items_with_commas'     => 'Separate moods with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'            => 'Add or remove moods',
        'choose_from_most_used'          => 'Choose from the most used moods',
        'not_found'                      => 'No moods found'
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'moods',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Moods' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'show_admin_column' => true

        )
    );
}
```

Then I created a `taxonomy-moods.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="content">

    <?php hu_get_template_part('parts/page-title'); ?>

    <div class="pad group">

        <div class="notebox">
            <?php echo term_description(); ?>
        </div>

<?php
  // set up or arguments for our custom query
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 11,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'moods',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => 'angry'
             )
        )
  );
  // create a new instance of WP_Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
?>

    <?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); // run the loop ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('group post-standard'); ?>>
    <div class="post-inner">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                    <?php hu_the_post_thumbnail('beatpost-thumb'); ?>
                <?php elseif ( hu_is_checked('placeholder') ): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/front/img/thumb-standard.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_format('video') && !is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>'; ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_format('audio') && !is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span>'; ?>
                <?php if ( is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>'; ?>
            </a>
            <?php if ( comments_open() && ( hu_is_checked( 'comment-count' ) ) ): ?>
                <a class="post-comments" href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></span></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!--/.post-thumbnail-->

        <div class="post-content">

            <h2 class="post-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2><!--/.post-title-->

            <div class="entry excerpt"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

            <div class="post-meta group">
            <p class="post-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></p><p class="post-date"><?php the_time('m/d/Y'); ?><span class="anglemobile"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span></p><p class="cat-posts"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> <?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?><span class="comment-text"> Comments</span></span></a></p>
            </div><!--/.post-meta-->
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-inner-->
</article><!--/.post-->
    <?php if ($count == 4) : ?>
    <div class="adsenseposts"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_3094702_en_v0" width="970" height="90"></div>
    <?php endif; $count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<div id="navigation">
<?php $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'mid_size' => 3,
    'end_size' => 1,
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) ); ?>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
  <article>
    <h1>Sorry...</h1>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
  </article>
<?php endif; ?>


    </div><!--/.pad-->
</section><!--/.content-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Which is set to "Angry" so currently only posts in that mood show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need all that. the query is already assumed becuase you are using a standard template.   So don't do a Wp_query.

Why not just try:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content();  //obviously put your content information here.
    ?> 
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

or with your code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('group post-standard'); ?>>
    <div class="post-inner">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                    <?php hu_the_post_thumbnail('beatpost-thumb'); ?>
                <?php elseif ( hu_is_checked('placeholder') ): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/front/img/thumb-standard.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_format('video') && !is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>'; ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_format('audio') && !is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span>'; ?>
                <?php if ( is_sticky() ) echo'<span class="thumb-icon"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>'; ?>
            </a>
            <?php if ( comments_open() && ( hu_is_checked( 'comment-count' ) ) ): ?>
                <a class="post-comments" href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></span></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!--/.post-thumbnail-->

        <div class="post-content">

            <h2 class="post-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2><!--/.post-title-->

            <div class="entry excerpt"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

            <div class="post-meta group">
            <p class="post-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></p><p class="post-date"><?php the_time('m/d/Y'); ?><span class="anglemobile"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></span></p><p class="cat-posts"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> <?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?><span class="comment-text"> Comments</span></span></a></p>
            </div><!--/.post-meta-->
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-inner-->
</article><!--/.post-->
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: So I was severely over complicating it lol, thanks rudtek that worked great.